# Caching the struct Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I create a cache for a struct pointer object in Objective-C? Is there any third party component for caching objects as Java and .NET have?

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct _news {
  references
  char *headline;
  char *story_url;
} news;
```

I have a double pointer for the above struct in an interface class. I would like to cache it for some time using Objective-C.

Comment: Your terminology is a little bit confusing. Structs are not objects in Objective-C. Are you trying to ask how to store a struct as an instance variable of an object?

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
// save
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:&p length:sizeof(news)];

// read
struct news *begin = (struct news *)[data bytes];
```

Comment: Where does the variable `p` come from?

Comment: That would be the pointer to the struct. struct news *p = ...;